# Send e-mail with multiple attachments using command line and sendmail

Tags: bash, email, sendmail, uuencode

Is it possible to send multiple attachments with `uuencode` and `sendmail`?

In a script I have a variable containing the files that need to be attached to a single e-mail like:

```
$attachments=attachment_1.pdf attachment_2.pdf attachment_3.pdf attachment_4.pdf
```

Also a `$template` variable like:

```
$template="Subject: This is the subject
From: no-reply@domain.com
To: %s
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body.
"
```

I have come up with:

```
printf "$template" "$recipient" |
sendmail -oi -t
```

Somewhere within this I must attach everything in the `$attachments` variable?

Comment: Is [mailx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailx) an option? If so, you can simple use the `-a` switch to send multiple emails. Do you *have* to use vanilla sendmail?

Comment: Check the answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940292/using-uuencode-to-attach-multiple-attachments-from-a-variable-to-an-e-mail-and-s It will give you an idea how to parse a variable containing attachments through uuencode.

Answer (score 6):

### `uuencode` attachemnts and send via `sendmail`

Sending MIME attachemnts is better.
`uuencode` is simpler to implement in scripts **but** email some clients DO NOT support it.

```
attachments="attachment_1.pdf attachment_2.pdf attachment_3.pdf attachment_4.pdf"
recipient='john.doe@example.net'

# () sub sub-shell should generate email headers and body for sendmail to send
(
# generate email headers and begin of the body asspecified by HERE document 
cat - <<END
Subject: This is the subject
From: no-reply@domain.com
To: $recipient
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body.

END
# generate/append uuencoded attachments
for attachment in $attachments ; do
  uuencode $attachment $attachment
done
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- $recipient
```

Comment: worked for me but it's sending some noname file as an attachment. how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, `mailx` also works well.

```
mailx -s "Subject" -a attachment1 -a attachement2 -a attachment3 email.address@domain.com < /dev/null
```